# PHP syntax error “unexpected $end” at last line

Tags: php

I have that code included to the main.php and received syntax error “unexpected $end” at last line of this code even I put the } for the while loop. Please help

```
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    ?>
    <div class="center_title_bar"><?php echo $row['ProName']?></div>
    <div class="prod_box_big">
        <div class="top_prod_box_big"></div>
        <div class="center_prod_box_big">
            <?php
            echo"<div class='product_img_big'>"; 
                echo"<a href='javascript:popImage('".$row['ProPicture']."','".$row['ProName']."') title='".$row['ProName']."'><img src='".$row['ProPicture']."' alt='' border='0' /></a>";
            echo"</div>";
            echo"<div class='details_big_box'>";
                echo"<div class='product_title_big'>'".$row['ProName']."'</div>";

                echo"<div class='specifications'>'".$row['ProInfo']."'<br />"; 
                    echo"Trạng thái: <span class='blue'>";
                    if($row['ProQuantity'])
                    {
                        echo"Còn hàng";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo"Hết hàng";
                    }
                    echo"</span><br />";
                    echo"Bảo hành: <span class='blue'>".$row[ProWarranty]." tháng</span><br />";
                echo"</div>";

                echo"<div class='prod_price_big'><span class='price'>".number_format($row['ProPrice'],0,',','.')." VND</span></div>";
                    echo'<a href="?options=giohang&action=add&item='.$row[ProID].'" class="addtocart">Thêm vào giỏ</a>';
                    ?> 
                    <a href="location:history.back()" class='compare'>Quay lại</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_prod_box_big"></div>
}
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in

Comment: The first error that pops out to me is `<?php echo $row['ProName']?>`... you're missing a semicolon. There might be more errors; I stopped looking after that one.

Comment: you are missing the } to close the while loop

Comment: But even I tried putting the last } to close the loop, I still have Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in

Comment: Almost, just updated my answer, see below.

Comment: Please open PHP tag before } and close PHP tag after } -- <?php } ?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the whole script, you forgot to close the `while` loop from the begining, at the end of the file.

You need to add:

```
<?php } ?>
```

at the end of the file.

Comment: Yeah, you're so brilliant.

Comment: Hm.. I can't find any other error in this script.. are you sure the error comes from this script?

Comment: Mr Greenish, can you help me analyze this code line:
`echo"<a href='javascript:popImage('".$row['ProPicture']."','".$row['ProName']."') title='".$row['ProName']."'><img src='".$row['ProPicture']."' alt='' border='0' /></a>";`

I just get back `<a href='javascript:popImage(` in my browser

Comment: The problem is, that you use `'` to set `href=''` and inside href you use the same `'` to define `popImage('','')` parameters. Try using `\"` instead of `'` for html attributes like href.

Answer (score 0):

this is the script without error

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="center_title_bar"><?php echo $row['ProName'] ?></div>
                    <div class="prod_box_big">
                        <div class="top_prod_box_big"></div>
                        <div class="center_prod_box_big">
                            <?php
                            echo"<div class='product_img_big'>";
                            echo"<a href='javascript:popImage('" . $row['ProPicture'] . "','" . $row['ProName'] . "') title='" . $row['ProName'] . "'><img src='" . $row['ProPicture'] . "' alt='' border='0' /></a>";
                            echo"</div>";
                            echo"<div class='details_big_box'>";
                            echo"<div class='product_title_big'>'" . $row['ProName'] . "'</div>";

                            echo"<div class='specifications'>'" . $row['ProInfo'] . "'<br />";
                            echo"Trạng thái: <span class='blue'>";
                            if ($row['ProQuantity']) {
                                echo"Còn hàng";
                            } else {
                                echo"Hết hàng";
                            }
                            echo"</span><br />";
                            echo"Bảo hành: <span class='blue'>" . $row[ProWarranty] . " tháng</span><br />";
                            echo"</div>";

                            echo"<div class='prod_price_big'><span class='price'>" . number_format($row['ProPrice'], 0, ',', '.') . " VND</span></div>";
                            echo'<a href="?options=giohang&action=add&item=' . $row[ProID] . '" class="addtocart">Thêm vào giỏ</a>';
                            ?> 
                        <a href="location:history.back()" class='compare'>Quay lại</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom_prod_box_big"></div>
            <?php
            }
```